# Pyspark - SparkStreaming - Python v3.5 - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to spark streaming, trying to read data present in Kafka broker.

Below is my code:

> ```
> def __init__(self):
>     self.spark = SparkSession \
>         .builder \
>         .appName("TestApp") \
>         .config("k1", "v1") \
>         .getOrCreate()
>     self.ssc = StreamingContext(self.spark.sparkContext, 1)
>
> def StreamingObject(self):
>     kafkaParams = {'metadata.broker.list': 'localhost:9092'}
>     topic = "Topic2"
>     topicpartion = TopicAndPartition(topic, 0)
>     fromoffset = {topicpartion: 0}
>     kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(self.ssc, [topic], kafkaParams, fromOffsets = fromoffset)
>     words = kvs.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(","))
>     words.pprint()
>
>     self.ssc.start()
>     self.ssc.awaitTermination()
> ```

Last step is to print whatsoever I am fetching from the broker but getting below error message.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/GCPProject/SStreaming.py", line 72, in <module>
    objss.StreamingObject()
  File "C:/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/GCPProject/SStreaming.py", line 40, in StreamingObject
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(self.ssc, [topic], kafkaParams, fromOffsets = fromoffset)
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 130, in createDirectStream
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper$$anonfun$17.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:717)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(MapLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(MapLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.foreach(MapLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.copyToBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:275)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.copyToBuffer(Traversable.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.toBuffer(MapLike.scala:326)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.toBuffer(Map.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.toSeq(MapLike.scala:323)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.toSeq(Map.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:717)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.6:4040
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-4ac3750b-cdf3-4d1d-823c-2b60f62db15a
19/09/18 23:23:43 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-4ac3750b-cdf3-4d1d-823c-2b60f62db15a\pyspark-e791b26d-bacb-47ab-b7ae-2ae66a811158
```

Data is in CSV format, present in Kafka broker. I am not sure where is the issue. Please help me out to fetch messages from Kafka broker.

I am working on `Spark 2.2.0` and `spark-streaming-kafka 0.9.0` and setup this environment in `windows`.

Comment: spark-streaming-kafka 0.9.0 doesn't exist...https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: that link says  spark-streaming-kafka 0.8.2.1 and higher version. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11/0.9.0.1

Comment: That group is `org.apache.kafka`, which you **should not** include into `streaming-kafka`. So, again, that `org.apache.spark` dependency does not exist., so are you using `0.8.2.1`, then?

Comment: I was using the wrong Jar. Now I am getting `Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition` error message after using the correct one.

Comment: Okay, so that comes from Kafka libraries, not Spark. In PySpark, you may need to add `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:<your kafka version>` as a package, only because it cannot resolve transitive dependencies.

Comment: Now, I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`. I am using Python 3.5 and this version doesn't support long data type. I don't want to change python version. Is there any way to overcome from this issue?

Comment: I don't think changing Python versions is going to fix a Java exception. Please edit your question to include the new error full stacktrace

Comment: I edited my question, updated error stack

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class`
occurs , may because your local scala version not match to the version of scala that spark depending on.

Please check your scala version. Spark 2.2.0 uses Scala 2.11